# jQuery - Submit Form and Refresh within the Div

Tags: jquery

I am trying to refresh the data in the DIV without reload entire page.  So, user enters a name in the CompanyName textbox and hit enter, I want the form submits, then my code will process, grab the new data from the database, and then display back to the "div1".

I have these DIVs below.

```
<div id="div1-wrapper">
    <div id="div1" style="border:solid 1px red; width: 100%;"> 
        <table width="90%" align="center" class="RowDetail">
            <tr>
                <--- The Data Refreshing Display Here --->
            </tr>
    </div>
</div>

<form name="form1" id="form1" method="post" action="PurchaseRequestList.asp" onsubmit="return     validSearch();">
    <input type="text" name="CompanyName" id="CompanyName" value=""  class="box2">
</form>
```

This is what I have tried so far, but no luck...

```
$('#CompanyName').on('keypress', function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13)
    {

        var url = 'PurchaseRequestList.asp';   
        $.ajax({
          method: 'post',
          url: url  + '?#div1',
          success: function(data) {
        $('#div1-wrapper').load(data);
    }
});
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: You'll need to focus your research efforts on 'ajax'.

Comment: I don't see any form to submit.

Comment: Follw this great tutorial: [5 Ways to Make Ajax Calls with jQuery](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/5-ways-to-make-ajax-calls-with-jquery/)

Comment: Updated the codes with the form.  thanks for helping.

Comment: @milacay The best way is learning. Google `jQuery Ajax Tutorial` or just follow the `above link`.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are calling `.submit()` on the form element. What you should do, is use jQuery ajax to submit the form data and use a success callback to update the div. To get the form data, you'll need to use `$.serialize()`; Try something like this.

```
   $( "form" ).on( "submit", function( event ) {
      var data =  $( this ).serialize();
      $.ajax({
        method: 'post',
        data: data,
        url: url  + '?#div1',
        success: function(res) {
          $('#div1-wrapper').load(res);
        }
      });
   });
```

Comment: He has to submit a form by ajax, where are parameters ??

Comment: I modified my codes with ajax as your suggest, but no luck.  I am new to Jquery, please help!

Comment: @hackNightly, I tried your suggestion, and it is not working. it is not refreshing the data in "div1". Thanks

Comment: method: should be type: